# Error intentando eliminar el servicio docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Estoy intentando desinstalar mi antigua version de doker 1.6.2. Cuando intento hacerlo en consola, me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error.:

[image: Trying to uninstall docker]

Si sabéis como eliminar la versión antigua o como actualizar Docker a la versión 1.9 sin tener que desinstalar la versión anterior, os agradecería que me dijeseis cómo.

Ya he intentado hacerlo con "purge" y otros comandos.

Comment: Hi Lu Cia, you asked in StackOverflow Spanish. If you want to ask in English please visit https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y copia-pega, tanto el comando que estás usando para eliminar el servicio como el resultado de ese comando. __No uses imágenes__, copia el resultado como texto, señálalo y usa el botón `{ }` para darle formato.